# How to dynamically cast GetDirectBufferAddress based on buffer type?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have a JNICall where `DirectByteBuffer` can be passed as `jobject buffer` like this.

```
    JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_JNIFoo_quickSelect0 (
             JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobject buffer)
```

In order to do some operations on the buffer, I need to know its type meaning whether its `LongBuffer` or `ShortBuffer` or `CharBuffer` or `IntBuffer` etc.

How can I know the type of the buffer dynamically to type cast it using `long *` or `short *` or `int *` like below?

```
    long * addr = (long *)(env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(buffer);
```

One way I can think of is getting the class name of the buffer and then inferring what type it is.

I don't mind asking the user to pass in the class type like `long.class` as well which will then be parameterised in native as `jclass`.

Update: In either of the potential solutions I suggested, I'd need to have if-else or switch for each possible primitive type. I am looking to see if there is a cleaner way say like this:

```
    T * addr = (T *)(env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(buffer);
```

Comment: "I don't mind asking the user to pass in the class type like long.class as well which will then be parameterised in native as jclass. " - why not do that then? Sounds like you already have a solution.

Comment: yea I'd love to but the problem is I'd need to have if-else or switch for each primitive type based on what `class` is passed. I have not been able to do this 

      
        `T * addr = (T *)(env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(buffer);`


I've updated my question to look for cleaner solution.

Comment: Just a note. You should cast native pointer to pointer to JNI types, i.e. not to `int *`, `long *` but to `jint *`, `jlong *` due to native and JNI types may have different sizes. Also you must ensure that buffer holds data stored in native endianess.